# Pulse Audio Virtual Device | Making it a 5.1 Channel audio device, and then distribute individual channels tto different devices

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, bluetooth, pulse-audio

What I am looking for is a way to make an aggregate device that allows you to split out the individual channels of the virtual device to individual channels of separate hardware devices.

I was looking for how to do this so that I could set up a 5.1 audio setup using large Bluetooth speakers, and many individual Bluetooth adapters. This would allow you to make a wireless, Bluetooth powered small speaker setup.

I have not found a way to do this with pulse audio on Ubuntu 18.04 yet, and have tried researching into loop devices and sinks. I personally think I may be missing something. It is ok not use pulse audio as long as it will work on Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks, Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [module-combine-sink](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index11h3) Pulseaudio module. You'll need a `channel_map` as described under *Device Drivers* on the same page.

See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443013/pulseaudio-simultanious-add-two-devices).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for, I knew I was missing something :)